# highcharts string in data: [ ]

Tags: jquery, json, highcharts

I would like to "print out" my string in an array, but it does not work.

If print the string in my console, everything looks correct. Even if I copy the string in the console and set it into data[] the pie is build correctly. Why does the source code shows me the variable name instead of the string?

[image]

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 
 var jsonCharts = {};
 
 var t = 0;
 var title = [];
 var d = 0;
 var data = [];
 
 var concat = "[";
 var len = 0;
 
 var color = ['#425d5f', '#c4ca5d', '#424821', '#878787', '#878e43', '#a5c7c7'];
  
 $(".title").each(function() {   
  title[t] = $(this).html();
  t++;
    });
 
 $(".data").each(function() {   
  data[d] = parseInt($(this).html());
  d++;
    });
 
 console.log(len);
 
 len = $(title).length;
 len--;
  
 $.each( title, function( i, l ){
  if(i < len){
   concat = concat + '{name: \'' + l + '\', y: ' + data[i] + ', color: \'' + color[i] + '\'}, ';
  }else{
   concat = concat + '{name: \'' + l + '\', y: ' + data[i] + ', color: \'' + color[i] + '\'}]';
  }
 });
  
 $(function() {
 console.log(concat);
  
  new Highcharts.Chart({
   chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'pie',
    height: 680,
    width: 680
   },

   series: [{
    innerSize: '65%',
    data: [ concat ]
   }]
  });
 });
});
```

```css
body{
   font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  }
  table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
   width: 600px;
  }

  td, th {
   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #dddddd;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

  <h1 style="padding:30px;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">Charts Example</h1>
  <h2 style="padding-left:30px;">Subtitle</h2>
 <div style="float:left;padding:30px;">
  <table id="charts">
    <tr>
   <th>IN USD</th>
   <th>2015</th>
   <th>2014</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="title">Area 1</td>
   <td class="data">939</td>
   <td>980</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="title">Area 2</td>
   <td class="data">525</td>
   <td>604</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="title">Area 3</td>
   <td class="data">242</td>
   <td>264</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="title">Area 4</td>
   <td class="data">181</td>
   <td>183</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="title">Area 5</td>
   <td class="data">119</td>
   <td>116</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td class="title">Area 6</td>
   <td class="data">23</td>
   <td>19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td><b>Total</b></td>
   <td><b>2,029</b></td>
   <td><b>2,166</b></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div style="float:left;">
  <div id="container" style="width: 720px; height: 400px;"></div>
 </div>
```

Thanks for helping me.

Best regards,
Yab86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue starts in this line:

```
var concat = "[";
```

You need to build an array of objects (not a string), so, replace the previous line with:

```
var concat = [];
```

In order to build the array of objects you can create on the fly each new object and [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) into the array:

```
$.each(title, function (i, l) {
    concat.push({name: l, y: data[i], color: color[i]});
});
```

Now, if you want to print the array of objects you can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var jsonCharts = {};

    var t = 0;
    var title = [];
    var d = 0;
    var data = [];

    var concat = [];
    var len = 0;

    var color = ['#425d5f', '#c4ca5d', '#424821', '#878787', '#878e43', '#a5c7c7'];

    $(".title").each(function () {
        title[t] = $(this).html();
        t++;
    });

    $(".data").each(function () {
        data[d] = parseInt($(this).html());
        d++;
    });

    // console.log(len);

    len = $(title).length;
    len--;

    $.each(title, function (i, l) {
        concat.push({name: l, y: data[i], color: color[i]});
    });

    // console.log(JSON.stringify(concat));

    new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie',
            height: 680,
            width: 680
        },

        series: [{
            innerSize: '65%',
            data: concat
        }]
    });

});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 600px;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<h1 style="padding:30px;border-bottom:1px solid #000;">Charts Example</h1>

<h2 style="padding-left:30px;">Subtitle</h2>

<div style="float:left;padding:30px;">
    <table id="charts">
        <tr>
            <th>IN USD</th>
            <th>2015</th>
            <th>2014</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Area 1</td>
            <td class="data">939</td>
            <td>980</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Area 2</td>
            <td class="data">525</td>
            <td>604</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Area 3</td>
            <td class="data">242</td>
            <td>264</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Area 4</td>
            <td class="data">181</td>
            <td>183</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Area 5</td>
            <td class="data">119</td>
            <td>116</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Area 6</td>
            <td class="data">23</td>
            <td>19</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Total</b></td>
            <td><b>2,029</b></td>
            <td><b>2,166</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">
    <div id="container" style="width: 720px; height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
```